# Paypal classic API: Failure with php CURL

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I am trying to setup a parallel payment using the paypal classic API. However, I am getting massive errors.

I have 2 test accounts setup in the sandbox as well as a classic application.

I am using PHP CURL to initiate the request. I updated the CURL code from the doc to php curl.

My PHP code as as follow:

```
$headers = array(
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: XXXXXX" ,
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: XXXXXX",
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: XXXXXX" ,
    "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV",
    "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV",
    "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: APP-80W284485P519543T",
    );

$post_array = array(
    'actionType'=>'PAY',
    'clientDetails.applicationId'=>'APP-80W284485P519543T',
    'currencyCode'=>'USD',
    'feesPayer'=>'SECONDARYRECEIVER',
    'receiverList.receiver(0).amount'=>'5.00',
    'receiverList.receiver(0).email'=>'primaryreceiver1@test.com',
    'receiverList.receiver(0).primary'=>'true',
    'receiverList.receiver(1).amount'=>'5.00',
    'receiverList.receiver(1).email'=>'secondaryreceiver1@test.com ',
    'receiverList.receiver(1).primary'=>'false',
    'requestEnvelope.errorLanguage'=>'en_US',
    'ipnNotificationUrl'=>'http://www.yourdomain.com/ipn_myreceiver',
    'returnUrl'=>'http://www.yourdomain.com/success',
    'cancelUrl'=>'http://www.yourdomain.com/cancel',
    );


$url = 'https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay';


$curl_session =  curl_init();       
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_array));
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10); 
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);                
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($curl_session);
echo $response;
```

I am getting the following error response:

> responseEnvelope.timestamp=2014-03-20T11%3A35%3A58.520-07%3A00&responseEnvelope.ack=Failure&responseEnvelope.correlationId=db88a73f724a0&responseEnvelope.build=10175386&error(0).errorId=580022&error(0).domain=PLATFORM&error(0).subdomain=Application&error(0).severity=Error&error(0).category=Application&error(0).message=Invalid+request+parameter%3A+email+secondaryreceiver1%40test.com++is+invalid&error(0).parameter(0)=email&error(0).parameter(1)=secondaryreceiver1%40test.com+

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the curl's `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` You are doing url encoding on the whole `$parameter`, which is wrong `urlencode($post)`.

For http POST the url encoding is done on this way:

```
$param = "key1=".urlencode($value1);
$param = $param . "&" . "key2=".urlencode($value2);
$param = $param . "&" . ".email=".urlencode('primaryreceiver1@test.com');
// and so on.
```

So change your POST parameters `urlencoding` according to above one and then try again.

**Note:** if your key1, key2, etc has special character then you have to do urlencode on them as well. For example if it is `xyz%32=value1` the you have to use it like `urlencode('xyz%32').'=value1'`

Comment: I have updated my code with http_build_query() to handle the post fields. However, I am still getting an error. Any idea why?

Comment: @PeterLur Nice improvement :-) From your error msg it says `email secondaryreceiver1@test.com  is invalid`. So I believe you have to concentrate on this with other post fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try using http_build_query for the post fields. I usually have success with that.

so something like

```
$post = array('actionType' => "PAY", 'value2 => "etc etc etc );
```

Then in your curl options

```
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have updated my code with http_build_query(). However, I am still getting an error.